# Incorrect php value sent in boostrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table displaying values in database using codeigniter. When I click on button of a line a modal shows up with a form that has the values of the table line. The problem is if I click on the first line, the second line values is sent to the modal and if I click on the second line the third line value is sent to the modal. How can I fix this ?

```
<table>

    <?php 
    foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee) {
        $employee = (object)$employee;
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?=$employee->id_acd;?></td>
        <td><?=$employee->nombre;?></td>
        <td><?=$employee->apellido;?></td>

    <td>
            <button data-toggle="modal"
            data-target="#myModal"
            data-employee-id="<?=$employee->id_acd;?>">
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php } ?>

</table>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
 <div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-body">
<form name="myModalTitle" id="myModalTitle" method="post" action="<?php
            echo site_url('user_Authentication/user_login_process');?>">
  <div> 
  <label>Nombre:</label>
 <input name="nombre" value="{{nombre}}" disabled>
     </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Apellido:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido"
   value="{{apellido}}" disabled>
  </div>
  <p>
    <button> Enviar </button>
  </p>
 </form>
    <script>
      var employees = <?=
    json_encode(
    $EMPLOYEES
    ); ?>;
     (function($){
     var myModalTitle = $( '#myModalTitle' );
    var myModalTitleText = myModalTitle.html();
   var myModal = $( '#myModal' );
   var btnOpenMyModal = $( '.btn-open-my-modal' );
   btnOpenMyModal.on('click', function() {
   var btn = $( this );
   var currentEmployees = employees[parseInt( btn.data( 'employee-id' ) )];
   myModalTitle.html(
  .replace( '{{nombre}}', currentEmployees.nombre )
     currentEmployees.telefono )
     );
     });
      }(jQuery));
     </script>
```

Comment: can you also add your employee data example so we can see what do you have there and not picking up the correct one

Comment: ok. this variable is from the controller :  public function display_demand(){

  $query = $this->account_demand_model->getDemands();
  $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
  if($query){
   $data['EMPLOYEES'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('display_demands', $data);
 }

Comment: no what I meant is the data, not the function. We don't have your database or rest of your models etc. what does that php function prints out?

Comment: it prints out all the data found in the table to the view page

Comment: and it is .....

Comment: I think you need to take a look at [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: [How Much Research Effort is Expected of Stack Overflow Users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/5827005)

Comment: My code works just the values in table line not matching those sent in modal windows. That s why i posted.

Comment: any help hmmmmm

Answer (score 0):

From that I guess `$EMPLOYEES` is an indexed array. In most languages it is zero-indexed, meaning the first element is `$EMPLOYEES[0]`.

If `employee-id` is just the index of the array, then add `+1` to this line:

```
var currentEmployees = employees[parseInt(btn.data('employee-id'))+1];
```

This is called an [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) error and is really common.